# C# Ascii conversion and back

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char, ascii

Alright, So im making a basic ceaser encryption program which offsets each character by a given amount, this is done by using the characters ASCII key then adding the amount which is should be offset by to the key.

Basically I can see why my program is not working and is not returning the string I want it to return, here is the pseudo code for encryption:

```
 `Type in text
  Type in encryption key
     Display Encrypt(text, key)
        function Encrypt(text,key)
          For each letter in text
            Get its ascii code
              add the key to the ascii code
                  Turn this new ascii code back to a character
                      Append character to ciphertext string
```

End for
return ciphertext`

The first input would be a sentance, and the second input is the number for it to be offset by

Here is my C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write a Sentance!");
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("How many characters do you want to ofset it by?");
        int key = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(encrypt(text,key));
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    static string encrypt(string text, int key)
    {
        string ciphertext = "";
        int y = 0;
        char[] letters = text.ToCharArray();
        for(int x = 0; x <= letters.Length; x++)
        {
            int AsciiLET = (int)letters[y];
            string Asciiletter = (AsciiLET + key).ToString();
            ciphertext += Asciiletter;
            y++;  
        }
        return ciphertext;

    }
```

Comment: "I can see why my program is not working" tell us why. Also post some expected input and output.

Comment: You don't use `key`. What's with that?

Comment: This code throws errors, just note it's best to put the errors in the question in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things wrong:

1. Can only go to one before `.Length`. i.e. `<` not `<=`
2. `x` not `y`, `y` removed
3. `ToString` on a number (`(AsciiLET + key)`), gives you a number in string, eg `"89"`
4. Use `key`

Now it looks like:

```
static string encrypt(string text, int key)
{
    string ciphertext = "";
    char[] letters = text.ToCharArray();
    for (int x = 0; x < letters.Length; x++) // see 1
    {
        int AsciiLET = (int)letters[x]; //2
        char Asciiletter = (char)(AsciiLET + key); //3 & 4
        ciphertext += Asciiletter;
    }
    return ciphertext;
}
```

Comment: Thats Great, thanks a bunch, is there any chance you could quickly explain exactly what the line which assigns Asciiletter does?

Comment: @user3063533 Just as you cast a `char` to an `int` on the line above that, so this casts from the `int` back to a `char`.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I would upvote you but I need more reputation so I can't.

Comment: No problem, I've given you an up vote to help your rep situation!